# Is there an efficient way to retrieve only a list of years without duplicates from DB?

Tags: mysql

Scenario: table may have thousands of records with a timestamp column.  But the thousands of records may have been timestamped with only two different years... or then again, maybe not.  All I'm looking for is the following array:

Years present in table:  array('0' => '2012', '1' => '2013')

I can get to that answer by manipulating the result, but I know it can't be very efficient; especially with potentially thousands of records.  What's the best way?

Comment: That's what I'm using now... but is that the most efficient?

Comment: Okay... that's what I wanted to confirm.  Thanks.

Comment: Then you should have included that in your question. But if you want the answerer to see your comment more easliy, you should comment on the answer..not the question.

Comment: My fault- he did comment on my comment, but I subsequently removed the comment and made it an answer ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(date_field) FROM table
```

Is this what you mean?